# .htaccess allow https non www, force www on http only

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Having troubles with Paypal subscriptions have held the old `https://example.com` domain in the paypal subscription profile and cannot be changed without cancel and re-subscribing.

what I have in place at the moment is forcing everything to `http://www.example.com` so `http(s)://example.com` 301 -> `http://www.example.com`

This is what I currently have.

paypal is trying to submit some subscriptions to `https://example.com/payments/ipn.php` it was doing a 301 redirect on https to `http://www.example.com` but you loose the POST data on a 301 redirect...

With the code below, `https://www.example.com` works, but since i need `https://example.com` for Paypal to work, i'm not sure how to allow the none www on the HTTPS domain without it redirecting to the HTTP host (`http://www.example.com`)

I added the robots.txt redirection to disallow / on https, this works as I don't want duplicate site on google.

I hope this has all made sense.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/payments)
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
 RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_ssl.txt [L]
```

HERE IS THE FIXED .htaccess for anyone that's interested!

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_ssl.txt [L]
    RewriteRule %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain\.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "none www on the HTTPS domain"

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to use the unsecured protocol?

Comment: The HTTP RFC says "If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request". In general responsing with 301 to a POST request asks for trouble.

Comment: I don't want to use www on the https domain, but I want to force it on the http domain.

As for the unsecured protocol, i found the website etc ran to slow running everything on https so I decided against it for now.

As for the 301 redirect, that's exactly my problem as I outlined above... "but you loose the POST data on a 301 redirect..."

Comment: `%{HTTPS_HOST}` does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter HTTPS you could use following RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  # if it's not HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or you could avoid a redirect, when it's a POST request, so the POST data wont be lost:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST  # if it's not POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Floern! I'll give that a shot and report back, thanks for "Answering" the question :-)

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
        RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.me%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
        RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_ssl.txt [L]
        RewriteRule %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain\.com%{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: Argh! above is what I used... I'll add it to the TOP part so it's formatted correctly

Comment: Edited the main question to include the Answer, but Floern pointed me in the right direction...